# Black Scholes differential

Tags: black-scholes, quantitative

I'm studying a BS derivation and I don't understand one part .We have a portfolio consisting of $\Delta(t)S(t)+B(t)$ where the first term is risky and the second is a riskless bond. The part i don't understand is why when we take the differential of this portfolio we obtain:
$\Delta dS +dB$. I understand the reason is related to the fact that this is the limit of a discrete model, so we can imagine $\Delta$ as a function of $t$ with more steps of lenght $\Delta t$ so in the limit $\Delta t \to0$. But this would mean that $\frac{\partial \Delta}{\partial S}=0$ that is $\frac{\partial^2 O}{\partial S^2}=0$ where $O$ is the derivative. Could anyone explain me this passage?

Comment: The reason is that we assume the quantity of the risk asset does not change during the infinitesimal interval $[t, t+dt]$, that is, it is self-financing.

Comment: Thank you, but the part i don't understand is this: in order to get BS equation we make the differential of the portfolio $d\Pi(t)$ and we set it equal to the differential of the derivative $dO(t)$ calculated by Ito's lemma. Now what i'm saying is that we are calculating a differential taking something constant, and this condition is not included in the differential $dO(t)$. So we can't say this object are equal. Am i wrong?

Comment: i discuss this extensively in my book "concepts and practice "

Answer (score 20):

In general, you won't be able to replicate the option by a portfolio of the form $\Delta_t S_t + B_t$, though it is possible to do so with a portfolio of the form $\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2B_t$; see [Chapter 3 of this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DGER5JG). Here, $B_t=e^{rt}$ is the value of the money-market account, and $r$ is the risk-free interest rate.

On the other hand, you can create a **locally risk-free** self-financing portfolio of the form 
\begin{align*}
X_t =\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2C_t, \tag{1}
\end{align*} 
where $C_t$ is the option price (see also [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26164/merton-model-riskless-self-financing-derivation/26298#26298)). 
Specifically, we assume that the stock price process $\{S_t, \, t > 0\}$ satisfies, under the probability measure $P$, an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t).
\end{align*}
As $X_t$ is self-financing, then
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= \Delta_t^1 dS_t + \Delta_t^2 dC_t\\
&= \Delta_t^1 S_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t) + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2 dt\right)\\
&=\left[\mu \Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \mu S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right)\right]dt \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \left(\sigma\Delta_t^1 S_t + \sigma \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\right)dW_t.
\end{align*}
Since $X_t$ is locally risk-free, we assume that $X_t$ earns the risk-free interest rate $r$, that is,
\begin{align*}
dX_t = r X_t dt, \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
&\left[\mu \Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \mu S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right)\right]dt \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \left(\sigma\Delta_t^1 S_t + \sigma \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\right)dW_t= r X_t dt.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1  + \Delta_t^2\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}=0, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\mu \Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \mu S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right) = r(\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2C_t),
\end{align*}
or, 
\begin{align*}
\mu S_t\left(\Delta_t^1 +\Delta_t^2 \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\right)  + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2\right) &= r(\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2C_t)\\
&=r\Delta_t^2(-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} S_t + C_t).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2\right) &= r\Delta_t^2(-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} S_t + C_t). \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Canceling the term $\Delta_t^2$ from both sides of $(4)$, we obtain the Black–Scholes equation of the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + r S_t \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2 -rC = 0. \tag{5}
\end{align*}

> Comments

Note that the quantity $\Delta_t^2$ is canceled from both sides of $(4)$, it is then tempting to set $\Delta_t^2=1$ and, consequently, $\Delta_t^1 = - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$. This is indeed adopted by some books, see, for example, [Introduction to the Mathematics of Financial Derivatives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012384682X), by Hirsa and Neftci, and [Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133456315), by John Hull. However, it is easy to see that the strategy $\left(- \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}, 1\right)$ is **not self-financing**, and the replicating portfolio value, for a European exercise style vanilla call option,
\begin{align*}
X_t = - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} S_t+C_t = -Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)
\end{align*}
does not satisfy $(2)$.

> Existence of Self-financing Strategy

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ above, we have that
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 = -\frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} X_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}
{\partial S}S}, \quad
\Delta_t^2 =\frac{X_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S}.
\end{align*}
In order for $(2)$ to be satisfied, we set
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 = -\frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} B_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}
{\partial S}S},\quad
\Delta_t^2 =\frac{B_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S}.
\end{align*}
Then, using the Black–Scholes equation $(5)$, it is easy to see that
\begin{align*}
dB_t &= \Delta_t^1 dS_t + \Delta_t^2 dC_t.
\end{align*}
That is, $(\Delta_t^1, \Delta_t^2)$ is a self-financing strategy.

In addition, we can derive the existence using the martingale representation theorem; see [Shreve](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192311X). 
Specifically, let $\lambda = (\mu-r)/\sigma$, and define the risk-neutral probability measure $Q$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dP}\big|_t = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 t - \lambda W_t}.
\end{align*}
Then $\tilde{W}= \{\tilde{W}_t, t \ge 0\}$, where $\tilde{W}_t = W_t + \lambda t$ is a standard Brownian motion under $Q$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t(r dt + \sigma d\tilde{W}_t),
\end{align*}
or 
\begin{align*}
d\left(\frac{S_t}{B_t}\right) = \frac{S_t}{B_t}\sigma d\tilde{W}_t,
\end{align*}

Let $C_T$ be the option payoff at maturity $T$. Then
\begin{align*}
C_t = B_tE_Q\left(\frac{C_T}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right),
\end{align*}
where $E_Q$ is the expectation operator under the probability measure $Q$, and $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set at time $t$. Note that, $\{C_t/B_t, t \ge 0\}$ is a martingale. Therefore, by the martingale representation theorem, there exists an adapted process $\{\kappa_t, 0\le t \le T\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{C_t}{B_t} &= C_0 + \int_0^t \kappa_u d\tilde{W}_u\\
&=C_0 + \int_0^t \frac{B_u\kappa_u}{\sigma S_u} d\left(\frac{S_u}{B_u}\right) :\equiv C_0 + \int_0^t \gamma_u d\left(\frac{S_u}{B_u}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\gamma_t = \frac{B_t\kappa_t}{\sigma S_t}$, for $0\le t \le T$. Then
\begin{align*}
dC_t &= d\left(B_t \frac{C_t}{B_t} \right)\\
&=rC_t dt + B_t\gamma_t d\left(\frac{S_t}{B_t}\right)\\
&=r(C_t -\gamma_tS_t) dt + \gamma_t dS_t.\tag{6}
\end{align*}
We seek adapted processes $\{\Delta_t^1, 0\le t \le T\}$ and $\{\Delta_t^2, 0\le t \le T\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
B_t &=\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2C_t,\tag{7}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
dB_t &= \Delta_t^1 dS_t + \Delta_t^2dC_t\\
&=\Delta_t^1 dS_t + r \Delta_t^2 (C_t -\gamma_tS_t) dt + \Delta_t^2\gamma_t dS_t.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 + \Delta_t^2\gamma_t=0. \tag{8}
\end{align*}
From $(7)$ and $(8)$,
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 = -\frac{\gamma_t B_t}{C_t - \gamma_t S_t}, \quad
\Delta_t^2 =\frac{B_t}{C_t - \gamma_t S_t}.
\end{align*}
It is then clear that
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2 C_t = B_t.
\end{align*}
Moreover, from $(6)$,
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 dS_t + \Delta_t^2dC_t &=rB_t dt = dB_t.
\end{align*}
That is, $(\Delta_t^1, \Delta_t^2)$ is a self-financing trading strategy.

Comment: Thank you again. So i have no problem with the rest of the derivation after the self-financing condition. Is it right if i say this:"$\Delta(t)$ is a step function with step lenght $dt$ and it becomes continuous in the limit $dt\rightarrow0$"? According to mathematical formalism i mean.

Comment: You are basically right. The quantity $\Delta(t)$ is assumed to be a constant over the infinitesimal interval $[t, t+dt]$.

Comment: Ok but is there a more formal way to state this thing? Because everything i read about self-financiability doesn't give credit to the continuous limit we are doing. I mean if i show this to my teacher of math he wouldn't agree with me

Comment: @Gordon: \begin{align*}
X_t = - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} S_t+C_t = -Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)
\end{align*} is self financing. The confusion arises due to simplification. Because by defintion self fiancing means no exogeneous captial infusion. And if you treat, $\Delta$ as a constant within the small time interval, $dX_t = \Delta dS - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$ and this satisfies the property of self-financing

Comment: @kasa: For self-financing, you need to check that $dX_t = -\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} dS + dC$. Here, $X_t = -Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$. You can compute all derivative and then see whether the self-financing condition is satisfied. See also the discussion in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @kasa: There is a $dS$ term in $dX_t$. However, there are only $dt$ terms in $-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS +dC$, using Ito's lemma. See also Page 100 of the book [Mathematical Methods for Financial Markets](https://www.amazon.ca/Mathematical-Methods-Financial-Markets-Jeanblanc/dp/1852333766/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1503413725&sr=8-1&keywords=mathematical+methods+for+financial+markets).