# Notion of risk-less portfolio in derivation of Black-Scholes

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-calculus

EDIT: As pointed out by Gordon in the comments, the portfolio I considered in my original post is neither self-financing nor (locally) risk-free.
Though the central question is still open. Suppose that we have a portfolio $P_t$ satisfying
$$dP_t=a(W_t,t)dt+b(W_t,t)dW_t.$$
Then, apparently, the portfolio is called (locally) risk-free iff $b(W_t,t)$ vanishes. My question is why this definition makes sense. After all, the coefficient $a(W_t,t)$ might depend on the Wiener process, and thus on the path we are given.

This was the original post:
I'm trying to understand the derivation of the Black-Scholes equation for an option by arbitrage considerations, and feel puzzled by the notion of  a risk-free portfolio.

As usual, let the price of the underlying stock be given by the Ito-process
$$dS_t=\mu S_t dt+\sigma S_t dW_t,$$
and let $V$ denote the price of the option. We then consider the portfolio
$$P_t=V_t+\Delta S_t.$$
If we assume that this portfolio is self-financing it satisfies
$$dP_t=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}\right)dt+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+\Delta\right)dS.$$
Then it is claimed that the choice $\Delta=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$ makes the portfolio risk-free because the $dS$ term vanishes. Hence it must grow at the risk-free rate
$$dP_t=rP_tdt.~(1)$$

I have some problem understanding why such a portfolio is considered to be risk-free. After all in the equivalent integral equation
$$P_t-P_0=\int_0^t a(W_s,s)ds,$$
where $a$ is the first bracket, we still integrate over the paths of the Wiener process (or some function thereof). So it still depends on the path we are given.

I came up with the following (heuristic) idea: since the paths of the Wiener process are continuous (almost surely), on a very small interval $[t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon]$ the term $a$ is bounded
$$a_0-k\leq a(W_t(\omega),t)\leq a_0+k.$$
By monotony of the integral the growth of $P_t$ is thus approximately linear in $t$ with rate between $a_0-k$ and $a_0+k$ (where $k$ may be arbitrarily small). Hence at this small time scale the portfolio should be approximately risk-free, and taking the limit should give equation $(1)$.
Such an argument does not seem to work for a potential $dS$ term because integration with respect to the Wiener process lacks monotony.

Comment: But your integral $dPt=rP_td_t$ is deterministic, there is no Wiener process there. That's why it's risk-free.

Comment: The portfolio $P_t=V_t+\Delta S_t$ is neither self-financing nor (locally) risk free; see discussion [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential/32187#32187).

Comment: @Gordon - While I agree with $P_t$ not being self-financing, it surprises me that you say it is not locally risk-free?

Comment: @dbluesk: I agree that this equation is deterministic. But if I understand correctly it should be a consequence of the riskfreeness (and the no arbitrage assumption).

Comment: @Gordon: In your linked comment the assumption that the portfolio is free of risk seems to imply that the $dW_t$-term in $X_t$ vanishes as well. Isn't that the same kind of argument?
Though the self financing aspect indeed seems fishy.
Thank you guys for your comments btw!

Comment: @LocalVolatility and Hanschuh, this is a common mis-understanding even in John Hull's book. For a vanilla European call option $V_t + \Delta S_t= Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$, which is not risk-free.Yes,  locally risk free implies that the dW terms goes to zero.

Comment: Should be $V_t+\Delta S_t= -Ke^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2)$.

Comment: @Gordon Many thanks for your comments (much appreciated, though I can not upvote them due to lack of reputation?)! I edited my original post accordingly. Quite an upleasant suprise that there are mistakes in the literature on such a basic topic...
Though I'm still wondering why vanishing of the $dW_t$-term equals risk-freeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the self-financing and locally risk-free issues of the portfolio $P_t= V_t +\Delta S_t$, see [this question](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852333766) and also discussions on Page 100 of the book [Mathematical Methods for Financial Markets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852333766) by Jeanblanc, Yor, and Chesney.

Note that a portfolio is locally risk-free means that it earns the risk free rate $r$ over the infinitesimal interval $[t, t+dt]$ (see the bottom part on Page 99 of [the above book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852333766)). That is,
\begin{align*}
dP_t = rP_t dt.
\end{align*}
In other words,
\begin{align*}
a(W_{t}, t) dt + b(W_{t}, t)dW_t =  rP_t dt.
\end{align*}
Consequently, $b(W_{t}, t)=0$ and
\begin{align*}
a(W_{t}, t) = rP_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for, thanks! (Again, I can not upvote your answer because I lack reputation.)