# Dynamic Delta Hedging And a Self Financing Portfolio

Tags: black-scholes, delta-hedging

Let's assume the usual Black Scholes assumptions hold. My question is related to an answer on [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential/32187#32187). There, the weights ($\Delta_t^1$,$\Delta_t^2$) are derived which form a locally risk free portfolio $$X_t =\Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2C_t$$ with $$\Delta_t^1 = -\frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} B_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}
{\partial S}S},\quad
\Delta_t^2 =\frac{B_t}{C_t - \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S}$$ It is emphasized that the strategy $(−∂C∂S, 1)$ is not self financing. I have no doubt about the derivation. Rather, I'm interested to know, in the context of dynamic delta hedging, is it actually valid to set $\Delta_t$ (the amount of the underlying to buy or sell) to $∂C∂S$ instead of $\Delta_t^1$ as shown above? For example, [in this paper on page 4](http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/Hedgeing/Dynamic%20Hedgeing.pdf) the authors investigate delta hedging strategies by setting $\Delta_t^1$ to $-∂C∂S$ (e.g. $N(d_1)$ for a European call option) and explicitly claim the self financing property. So how would one actutally compute the correct $\Delta_t$ for a delta hedging strategy in a BS world?

Comment: See answer by the same user to the following question: [Derivation of BS PDE problem using Delta hedging](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thx for the link. To clarify, say, if I were to do a delta hedging simulation and therefore would have to compute the amount of the underlying to sell or buy on some discrete points using only $\Delta_t$ = $∂C∂S$, in general, I would obtain **delta neutrality** but **not** a self financed or locally risk free position? Wouldn't it be more correct then to use $\Delta_t^1$?

Comment: If you differentiate $X_t$ in that case $-$ hedging strategy $(-\partial C/\partial S,1)$ $-$ you get: $\frac{\partial X}{\partial S} = -\frac{\partial \Delta}{\partial S}S - \Delta + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} = -\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}S$ so you will be indeed $\Delta$-neutral but not $\Gamma$-neutral if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I see but my crucial question is about how to compute the $\Delta_t$ for delta hedging. Browsing the web reveals many sources (such as the [linked paper above](http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/Hedgeing/Dynamic%20Hedgeing.pdf)) which use $\partial C/\partial S$ and claim self-financing. I may miss something here.

Comment: Thx, if you find the time for a proper answer I can accept it.

Comment: The correct approach is the one described in the questions you and I linked to. You can also check the comments from users Gordon and zer0hedge at the bottom of the answer I linked to, it seems this mistake is common $-$ I also made it. Note that is in part due to the fact that the pricing PDE **does not** depend on the weight $\Delta_t^2$: this is because as you can observe $\Delta_t^1$ is a function of $\Delta_t^2$, hence in the process of deriving the PDE $\Delta_t^2$ ends up being cancelled: $ dX = rXdt \Leftrightarrow \Delta^2f(C,S)=r\Delta^2g(C,S)dt $.

Comment: I have added a detailed answer to your question @Tim, where I show that the hedging strategy $(1,\partial C/\partial S)$ is not self-financing. W.r.t. the article you link to in your previous comment, if you are referring to the 1st equation in page 4, please note that in that case the portfolio has an additional asset, the risk-free bond, which is hold in quantities so as to make the portfolio with weights $(w_C,w_S)=(1,\partial C/\partial S)$ self-financing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Main references

As explained in my comments, the correct approach to derive the hedging portfolio would be the one described in Gordon's answers to the following questions:

- [Derivation of BS PDE problem using Delta hedging](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Black Scholes differential](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential?noredirect=1&lq=1)

### The hedging portfolio $C_t-(\partial C/\partial S)S_t$ is not self-financing

We can check that the hedging portfolio $(w_C,w_S)=(1,-\partial C/\partial S)$ is not self-financing. Letting $X_t$ be the portfolio value, we have $-$ dropping time subscripts:

$$ \begin{align}
dX & = dC+d(w_SS)
\\[6pt]
& =dC+\left(Sdw_S+w_SdS+dw_SdS\right)
\end{align} $$

The differential of the option is:

$$dC = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\mu S dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\sigma SdW+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt$$

We differentiate the weight $w_S$:

$$ \begin{align}
dw_S & =\frac{\partial w_S}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial w_S}{\partial S}dS+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 w_S}{\partial S^2}dS^2
\\[6pt]
& = \frac{\partial w_S}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial w_S}{\partial S}\mu Sdt+\frac{\partial w_S}{\partial S}\sigma SdW+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 w_S}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt
\\[6pt]
& = -\left(\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\mu Sdt+\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma SdW+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3C}{\partial S^3}\sigma^2S^2dt\right)
\end{align} $$

Hence:

$$ \begin{align}
& Sdw_S = -\left(\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S\partial t}Sdt + \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\mu S^2dt+\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma S^2dW+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3C}{\partial S^3}\sigma^2S^3dt\right)
\\[6pt]
& w_SdS = -\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\mu Sdt+\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\sigma SdW\right)
\\[6pt]
& dw_SdS = -\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt
\end{align} $$

Terms cancel and we obtain:

$$ \begin{align}
dX = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt & - \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S\partial t}Sdt - \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\mu S^2dt 
\\[6pt]
& - \frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma S^2dW - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^3C}{\partial S^3}\sigma^2S^3dt -
 \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt
\end{align} $$

Hence we conclude that the self-financing condition $dX = dC+w_SdS$ is not verified: indeed the term in $\partial^2C/\partial S \partial t$ would not appear if it was self-financing, in which case it would read:

$$ \begin{align}
dX & = \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\mu S dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\sigma SdW+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt\right)-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}\left(\mu Sdt + \sigma SdW \right)
\\[6pt]
& = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\sigma^2S^2dt
\end{align} $$

### Independence of the pricing PDE and the option weight $w_C$

Note that the confusion around the hedging portfolio is in part due to the fact that the pricing PDE **does not** depend on the weight of the option $w_C$. As stated in your question, the correct stock weight $w_S$ is:

$$w_S = -w_C\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$$

Recall that after having cancelled the random terms in $dX_t$ through the choice of $(w_C, w_S)$, we get:

$$ dX_t = w_C \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2 \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}\right)dt$$

From the risk-free return constraint, we then obtain $-$ dropping time subscripts:

$$ \begin{align}
& dX = rXdt
\\[6pt]
\Leftrightarrow \quad & w_C \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\right)dt = r\left(w_SS+w_CC \right)dt
\\[6pt]
\Leftrightarrow \quad & w_C \left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2C}{\partial S^2}\right) = rw_C \left(-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S + C\right)
\end{align} $$

Hence the derivative weight $w_C$ can be cancelled.

### A note on hedging portfolios

Note the difference between our approach and the one described in your paper:

- Here, we hold a portfolio of options and stocks and we require this portfolio to return the risk-free rate;
- In your paper, we hold a portfolio made up on an option combined with stocks and riskless bonds and we require its value to be $0$.

$$\underbrace{w_C(t)C_t + w_S(t)S_t = B(t)}_{(1) \, \text{Our hedging portfolio}} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \underbrace{C_t + w_S(t)S_t + w_B(t)B(t) = 0}_{(2) \, \text{Your paper's hedging portfolio}}$$

The self-financing condition is different in both cases:

$$ \begin{align}
& (1) \; : \; C_tdw_C(t) + dw_C(t)dC_t + S_tdw_S(t) + dw_S(t)dS_t = 0
\\[12pt]
& (2) \; : \;  S_tdw_S(t) + dw_S(t)dS_t + B_tdw_B(t) + dw_B(t)dB_t = 0
\end{align} $$

Comment: A lil late thank you for this, I really appreciate!

Answer (score 4):

for a self financing portfolio, you have a holding in stocks and one in bonds. 
If we want to do a hedging simulation, at the start of each step, work out the total value of the hedger's holding (excluding the thing being hedged). Treat this as a cash sum. Buy $N(d_1)$ units of the stock. Use the rest of the money (which may be negative) to buy riskless bonds. Hold this across the step. Repeat.

This is trivially self-financing and you will find that the variance of the net position goes to zero as the step size goes to zero.