# Justify a backward differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, finance-mathematics

[image]

Regards of 4.5.1, how we get 4.5.5?

Comment: What book/paper is this from

Comment: It is a book by Jianfeng Zhang on BSDEs https://books.google.com/books?id=AV4yDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Oh nice. It looks pretty thorough. I'll probably check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for the replicating portfolio to be self-financing it suffices that <sup>(1)</sup>:
$$\lambda_t=\frac{V_t-h_tS_t}{B_t}$$
where I have changed the notation by designating by $B_t$ the money market account:
$$B_t=B_0e^{rt}$$
Hence, because the portfolio is self-financing, its dynamics are:
$$\begin{align}
dV_t&=\left(\frac{V_t-h_tS_t}{B_t}\right)dB_t+h_tdS_t
\\[5pt]
&=r(V_t-h_tS_t)dt+(\mu h_tS_tdt+\sigma h_tS_tdW_t)
\end{align}$$
Now, you can either be in a position to lend ($V_t>h_tS_t$) or borrow money. If the rates to lend $r_1>0$ and borrow $r_2<0$ are different then the equation above changes to:
$$dV_t=r_1\max(V_t-h_tS_t,0)dt-r_2\min(V_t-h_tS_t,0)dt+h_tdS_t$$
You lend at $r_1$ if you have excess cash in your hedging account, namely the value of your hedge $h_tS_t$ is lower than the value of the derivative $V_t$, otherwise you borrow at $r_2$. Note that:
$$\begin{align}
V_t>h_tS_t \Leftrightarrow &\ r_1\max(V_t-h_tS_t,0)-r_2\min(V_t-h_tS_t,0) 
\\
&= r_1(V_t-h_tS_t)>0
\\[3pt]
V_t<h_tS_t \Leftrightarrow &\ r_1\max(V_t-h_tS_t,0)-r_2\min(V_t-h_tS_t,0) 
\\ &= -r_2(V_t-h_tS_t)<0
\end{align}$$
Namely, the $\max$ and $\min$ functions allow to separate the excess/deficit of cash cases.

<sub>(1) Proving this is extremely cumbersome. Basically you need to prove that:
$$B_td\lambda_t+d\lambda_tdB_t+S_tdh_t+dS_tdh_t=0$$ 
If I find the time (and energy) I'll try to post a derivation, otherwise you can check [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see how to do this.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. but I am confusing that how the min/max appears in the equation. Is this mean that we want to maximize the value of $dV_t$?

Comment: @jf1997 see my updated answer, the $\max$ and $\min$ functions allow to separate the excess/deficit of cash cases.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @jf1997 I have slightly amended my answer as there was something wrong, strictly speaking the holding $\lambda_t$ of bank account has to be divided by $B_t$ (i.e. the value of the bank account) to ensure the replicating portfolio equals the derivative value $V_t$.