# Black Scholes derivation: Why treat Delta as a constant?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In the derivation of the Black-Scholes equation, it is argued (e.g. in the original paper and in Hull) that
$$dV(S_t, t)=(…)dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS_t,$$
where $V(S_t, t)$ is the value at time $t$ of an option on an asset with price process $S$. Thus, adding an amount of $-\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$ assets to the option would make the resulting portfolio $P$ riskless since
$$dP(S_t, t) \\ =(…)dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS_t - d(\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} S_t) \\ =(…)dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS_t - \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS_t \\ = (…)dt. $$

Why is the second equation true? We are treating $\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$ like a constant when pulling it out of the derivative while it is actually a function of $t$ and $S$. Wouldn’t we have to use the Ito Product Rule here? (and I wouldn’t know how to do that since I don’t know the dynamics of $\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$)

Comment: This is related to the Self Financing Condition, as explained in other posts here such as https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential/

Comment: See also discussions in [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34027/derivation-of-bs-pde-problem-using-delta-hedging?noredirect=1&lq=1).