# How to derive Black-Scholes equation with dividend?

Tags: options, black-scholes, finance-mathematics, mathematics, derivation

> Question: The [Black-Scholes equation without dividend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_equation) is given by 
>   $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + rS \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}  -rV = 0.$$
>   (I attempted to derive the equation in my [previous post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/is-my-derivation-of-black-scholes-equation-correct-or-am-i-missing-something-eg).)
>
> If we assume that 'with dividend rate $D$', then the Black-Scholes equation becomes 
>   $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + (r-D)S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}  -rV = 0.$$
>   How to derive this?

By working backwards and assuming derivation of my previous post, we should have 
$$d\Pi = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}dt - \Delta S - D\Delta Sdt.$$
But I do not understand why can we add the term in $d\Pi.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that the stock price process $\{S_t,\,t>0\}$ satisfies, under the real-world probability measure $P$, an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dS_t=S_t\big((\mu-q)dt+\sigma dW_t\big),
\end{align*}
where $\{W_t, \, t >0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion.
Here, we need to consider the total return asset $e^{qt}S_t$, that is, the asset with the dividend payments invested in the same underlying stock.
We consider a locally risk-free self-financing portfolio of the form 
\begin{align*}
\pi_t =\Delta_t^1 \big(e^{qt}S_t\big) + \Delta_t^2 V_t, 
\end{align*} 
where $V_t$ is the option price. Then, 
\begin{align*}
d\pi_t &= \Delta_t^1 d\big(e^{qt}S_t\big) + \Delta_t^2 dV_t\\
&= \Delta_t^1 e^{qt}\big(q S_t dt + dS_t \big) + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2 dt\right)\\
&=\left[\mu\Delta_t^1 e^{qt} S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (\mu-q) S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right)\right]dt \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad + \left(\sigma\Delta_t^1 e^{qt}S_t + \sigma \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)dW_t.
\end{align*}
Since $\pi_t$ is locally risk-free, we assume that $\pi_t$ earns the risk-free interest rate $r$, that is,
\begin{align*}
d\pi_t = r \pi_t dt, 
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
&\left[\mu \Delta_t^1 e^{qt} S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (\mu-q) S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right)\right]dt \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \left(\sigma\Delta_t^1 e^{qt} S_t + \sigma \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)dW_t= r \pi_t dt.
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\sigma\Delta_t^1 e^{qt}S_t + \sigma \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}=0, \tag{1}
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\mu e^{qt} \Delta_t^1 S_t + \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (\mu-q) S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right) = r(\Delta_t^1 e^{qt}S_t + \Delta_t^2 V_t).
\end{align*}
From $(1)$, 
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^1 = -e^{-qt} \Delta_t^2 \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}.
\end{align*} 
Then,
\begin{align*}
-\mu \Delta_t^2 S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+ \Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (\mu-q) S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2   \right) = r\Big(-\Delta_t^2 S_t\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \Delta_t^2 V_t\Big),
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
\Delta_t^2\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} -q S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2\right) &= r\Delta_t^2\Big(-\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} S_t + V_t\Big). \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Canceling the term $\Delta_t^2$ from both sides of $(2)$, we obtain the Black–Scholes equation of the form
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + (r-q) S_t \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \sigma^2S_t^2 -rV = 0. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Grossly oversimplifying, if the risk-free interest rate is 5% and the dividend is 3%, it seems like the underlying would have to increase by only 2% (roughly) for the instrument holder to breakeven with a risk-free portfolio? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Over an infinitesimal interval, I agree with your observation.

Comment: But not over a full year?

Comment: no, only locally.

Comment: Why not over a full year?

Comment: You may ask as another question. It won't be a short answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference in the derivation when you have a dividend-yield paying stock lies in the value of the Riskless Portfolio $\Pi_t$.

The financial meaning here is the key: to delta-hedge your option you buy a quantity $\Delta$ of the stock $S$, and only the stock is paying you the dividend, so you have to add this contribution in time to your hedge. 
The change in value of the stock is therefore:
$$
dS=(\mu-q)Sdt+\sigma S dW.
$$ 
We short a quantity $\Delta$ of the stock
\begin{equation}
 \Pi=V-\Delta S.
\end{equation}
 In the interval $dt$ the portfolio variation is therefore given by:
\begin{equation}
d\Pi= dV - \Delta dS - q \Delta S dt.
\end{equation}
The last term $ qS\Delta dt$ denotes the value added to the portfolio due to the dividend yield.

Now, for the Ito's Lemma the value of $dV$ is:
$$
dV= \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} \right) dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS.
$$
Finally you use the no arbitrage condition which states that a riskless portfolio has the same value as a riskless zero-coupon bond, *i.e.* $d\Pi=r\Pi dt$.
Substituting you finally obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + (r-q)S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S}  -rV = 0
$$
where you can see directly the additional $q$ term to the hedging due to the dividend yield.

Comment: I do not understand why we minus dividend in $dS.$

Comment: When a company pays dividends its value decrease, then the same appens to its stock value.

Comment: first:
$$
r \Pi dt = r \left( V - \Delta S \right) dt = (\Theta + \frac{1}{2} \left( \sigma  S \right)^2 \Gamma ) dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS - \Delta dS - q \Delta S dt.
$$
and then, delta hedging ( *i.e.* $\Delta = \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} $) and substituting, you find the correct answer. Financially you can think exactly as @gk94 suggested. If S is the price of my stock and it pays a dividend (think of it as a discrete dividend) then this value drops of the dividend amount.

Comment: See [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32171/black-scholes-differential/32187#32187). The portfolio $\Pi = V-\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} S$ may not be self-financing.